# Scala: constructor orders in inheritance

Tags: scala

Can someone explain me in detail about orders in which constructors are called in inheritance in scala please? Say I have:

```
abstract class A {
   private var data: T = compute()
   protected def compute(): T
}

class ImpA extends A {
   var a = 0
   override def compute() {
      a = 1
      null.asInstanceOf[T] // doesn't matter
   }
}

val inst = new ImpA
```

Then it appears that `inst.a == 0`, so I guess that what happens is that when `ImpA`'s constructor is called then, `A` constructor is called also, which actually triggers `compute()` that should set `a = 1`. But then scala goes back down to `ImpA`'s constructor and reset `a = 0`. Is that it?

Is there some well-known pattern to avoid this properly? (I'm not really trying to fix this problem that can be easily dealt with, though if there are patterns that are advised I'm eager to know them; but I'd rather like to have a deep understanding of what's happening, and hopefully know why reinitializing the variable `a` could be interested in that case. And also what would happen internally if it was a `val` as it would lead to assign several references to the same variables if the logic is kept...).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** something *fun* also is when you just change `ImpA.a` and use a reference instead of a `var`:

```
class ImpA extends A {
   class B {
     var b = 0
   }
   val b = new B
   override def compute() {
      b.b += 1
      null.asInstanceOf[T] // doesn't matter
   }
}
```

then it throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException` because `b` isn't instantiated yet. Following `Yuval Itzchakov` solution, here's what it compiles into:

```
  abstract class A extends Object {
      private[this] var data: Object = _;
      <accessor> private def data(): Object = A.this.data;
      <accessor> private def data_=(x$1: Object): Unit = A.this.data = x$1;
      protected def compute(): Object;
      def <init>(): test.A = {
        A.super.<init>();
        A.this.data = A.this.compute();
        ()
      }
    };
    class ImpA extends test.A {
      private[this] val b: test.ImpA$B = _;
      <stable> <accessor> def b(): test.ImpA$B = ImpA.this.b;
      override def compute(): Unit = {
        ImpA.this.b().b_=(ImpA.this.b().b().+(1));
        {
          (null: Object);
          ()
        }
      };
      override <bridge> <artifact> def compute(): Object = {
        ImpA.this.compute();
        scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT
      };
      def <init>(): test.ImpA = {
        ImpA.super.<init>();
        ImpA.this.b = new test.ImpA$B(ImpA.this);
        ()
      }
    };
    class ImpA$B extends Object {
      private[this] var b: Int = _;
      <accessor> def b(): Int = ImpA$B.this.b;
      <accessor> def b_=(x$1: Int): Unit = ImpA$B.this.b = x$1;
      <synthetic> <paramaccessor> <artifact> protected val $outer: test.ImpA = _;
      <synthetic> <stable> <artifact> def $outer(): test.ImpA = ImpA$B.this.$outer;
      def <init>($outer: test.ImpA): test.ImpA$B = {
        if ($outer.eq(null))
          throw null
        else
          ImpA$B.this.$outer = $outer;
        ImpA$B.super.<init>();
        ImpA$B.this.b = 0;
        ()
      }
    }
```

Though it's a bit harder to understand properly, it explains quite straightforwardly why the `NullPointerException` is thrown.

But if you use this time a `lazy val b = new B`, then it works:

```
class ImpA extends test.A {
  @volatile private[this] var bitmap$0: Boolean = false;
  private def b$lzycompute(): test.ImpA$B = {
    {
      ImpA.this.synchronized({
        if (ImpA.this.bitmap$0.unary_!())
          {
            ImpA.this.b = new test.ImpA$B(ImpA.this);
            ImpA.this.bitmap$0 = true;
            ()
          };
        scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT
      });
      ()
    };
    ImpA.this.b
  };
  lazy private[this] var b: test.ImpA$B = _;
  <stable> <accessor> lazy def b(): test.ImpA$B = if (ImpA.this.bitmap$0.unary_!())
    ImpA.this.b$lzycompute()
  else
    ImpA.this.b;
  override def compute(): Unit = {
    ImpA.this.b().b_=(ImpA.this.b().b().+(1));
    {
      (null: Object);
      () 
    }
  };
  override <bridge> <artifact> def compute(): Object = {
    ImpA.this.compute();
    scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT
  };
  def <init>(): test.ImpA = {
    ImpA.super.<init>();
    ()
  }
};
```

Comment: Edit: Never mind, I'm too stupid to read...

`compute()` isn't called anywhere. You just defined it.

Comment: @StefanFischer `compute` is called in `A`s constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what the compiler generates when compiling (using the `-Xprint:jvm` flag):

```
class ImpA extends com.testing.A {
  private[this] var a: Int = _;
  <accessor> def a(): Int = ImpA.this.a;
  <accessor> def a_=(x$1: Int): Unit = ImpA.this.a = x$1;
  override def compute(): String = {
    ImpA.this.a_=(1);
    (null: String)
  };
  override <bridge> <artifact> def compute(): Object = ImpA.this.compute();
  def <init>(): com.testing.ImpA = {
    ImpA.super.<init>();
    ImpA.this.a = 0;
    ()
  }
};
```

What do we see? We see that the constructor running for `ImplA` (defined as the `<init>` method) first calls `ImpA.super.<init>()`, which is a call to `A` to initialize itself first. `A`s initialization code looks like this:

```
def <init>(): com.testing.A = {
  A.super.<init>();
  A.this.data = A.this.compute();
  ()
}
```

It calls `A.super`, which is `Object`, and then calls `A.this.compute()`. This method initializes `a` to hold the value 1. Once that initialization finishes, `ImplA` sets `a` to `0`, as you told it to do during constructor initialization. That is why you're seeing the value `0` for `a`.

To sum up, the execution flow is as follows:

1. `ImplA` calls `A`s init method
2. `A` calls `compute`, which is invoked on `ImplA`
3. `ImplA.compute` assigns `a` the value `1`
4. `ImplA` assigns `a` the value `0`

For more, see http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html

Comment: Thanks I did not even think to use `-Xprint:jvm` flag! I'll get to see what happens with my edit then and understand by myself the NPE! =)

Comment: @som-snytt thanks! It helps understand indeed. I also found out that setting it to a `lazy val` (but needs to put the `var a` into a binding class) works just fine also (see my edit of the question).